# KIVY Change text of id does not work KIVY

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to update a text on my app with an id but it does not seem to update the text at all. I have a python file myfirebase.py and a kivy file signinscreen.kv.

The label id is "login_message" that I am trying to update. It is supposed to be updated in the python file with the following command:
App.get_running_app().root.ids['signin_screen']
.ids['login_message'].text = 'invalid username or
password'

There is no error; but it simply does not update the text of the label.

myfirebase.py:

python file
"""

```
  import requests
  import json
  from kivy.app import App

  class MyFirebase():

       def sign_in(self, username, password):

           result_users = 
           requests.get("https://uniquedatabase-c4647- 
           default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/" + "users" + ".json")
           data_users = 
                    json.loads(result_users.content.decode())

           incorrect_info = True

           for users in data_users.values():
              if username == users['username']:
              passcode = users['password']
                   if password == passcode:
                        incorrect_info = False
                        App.get_running_app().my_user_id = 
                                                        users
                        App.get_running_app().change_screen
                                             ('home_screen')
                        break

       if incorrect_info:
    
            App.get_running_app().root.ids['signin_screen']
            .ids['login_message'].text = 'invalid username or 
            password'
```

"""
Kivy file
"""

```
<SigninScreen>:
     FloatLayout:
         GridLayout:
              rows: 1
              pos_hint: {"top": 1, "right": 1}
              size_hint: 1, .2
              Image:
                  source: 'images/Uniquelogo.jpg'
                  size: self.texture_size
        TextInput:
             id:login_username
             hint_text: "username"
             size_hint: .8,.1
             pos_hint: {"top": .7, "right": .9}
        TextInput:
            id:login_password
            hint_text: "password"
            size_hint: .8,.1
            pos_hint: {"top": .5, "right": .9}
        Label:
           id: login_message
           text: ''
           size_hint: .8,.1
           pos_hint: {"top": .3, "right": .9}
           color: 1,0,0,1
        Button:
           pos_hint: {"top": .2, "right": 0.75}
           size_hint: 0.5, 0.25
           text: 'Sign In'
           color: 0,0,0,1
           background_normal: ''
           background_color: 1,0.95,0,1
           on_release:
              app.my_firebase.sign_in(login_username.text, 
              login_password.text)
```

"""

Comment: There is some really odd stuff going on in terms of indentation in your Python code sample.

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example, it's likely you aren't updating what you think you are but hard to say without seeing the problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

Your MyFirebase() instance is executed in a different thread.

Kivy uses the main thread to update UI components so that you should do the following:

- In your Kivy app, define a couple of functions to update your screen:

```py
from kivy.clock import mainthread


class YourApp(App):

    @mainthread
    def on_correct_info(self, users):
        self.my_user_id = users
        self.change_screen('home_screen')

    @mainthread
    def on_incorrect_info(self):
        self.root.ids['signin_screen'].ids['login_message'].text = 'invalid username or password'
```

- Your MyFirebase() class:

```py
from kivy.clock import Clock


if password == passcode:
    Clock.schuedule_once(lambda dt: App.get_running_app().on_correct_info(users))
else:
    Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: App.get_running_app().on_incorrect_info())
```

Reference - https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Working-with-Python-threads-inside-a-Kivy-application

Comment: it is still not updating the text of the label; did not change something

Comment: `on_correct_info()` or `on_incorrect_info()` is called correctly? You can put logger inside the functions to check.

Comment: Yes they are definitely called. that is not the issue. rather the text of the label is supposed to be changed but does not change on the app screen.